# Reopen or Migrate LyX & MiKTeX installation question

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

This question was closed as "too localized":

[LyX & MiKTeX installation problems on Windows 7](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/97296/22128)

The definition given for "too localized" begins with:

> *"This question is unlikely to help any future visitors..."*

However, the fact that this question has been viewed over 5,000 times seems to demonstrate that there is at least some interest in it. Also, there's now [this comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/97296/lyx-miktex-installation-problems-on-windows-7?noredirect=1#comment330441_97296):

> I don't see why this is closed! There are more than a few users of Windows 7 that are interested in using LyX. It's very frustrating to find a question that is exactly on point with a question I have but to see it closed...

I would like to see this question re-opened, since it seems apparent that it is *not* an issue isolated enough to truly warrant closure as "too localized". If the question is still off-topic however, I would suggest it be migrated to [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/).

Comment: Are you still looking for a solution, (I hope not, given the time that has passed) or do you have one to offer?  I think you make a good case for reopening.

Comment: I have the fifth vote on it but I don't know how we can resolve this issue other than reporting to LyX developers hence my vote. I think this is one of the rare cases that the closing reason applies to the question

Comment: @AlanMunn I think I abandoned the issue awhile ago, myself. But it seems evident to me that others are interested in a fix. The recent comment in my Inbox is what caught my attention.

Comment: @Well now I'm on the fence. If it's true that it's a bug in the LyX installer, and can only be addressed by the LyX development team, then I think the question should stay closed. If it's been fixed (although the comment suggests otherwise) and there's an answer to be added, it's certainly worth reopening to add that.  But otherwise, I'm now inclined to agree with percusse.